# What is the stick, dug with young plants for support, called?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, plant-physiology

I am looking for the word/name that describes a stick dug along with young plants to support/direct the plant growth.[image: Picture of the stick here]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just called a ["stake"](https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/112731/GROW-740895.html).

> [A piece of wood or other material](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stake#Noun), usually long and slender, pointed at one end so as to be easily driven into the ground as a marker or a support or stay.

Comment: is there no specific term in botany or for context related to plants?

Comment: Uh, "garden stake"?

Comment: In the UK light ones like those in the picture are usually called 'sticks' or 'canes' (they are usually bamboo so 'canes' is the more common). 'Stake' is usually reserved for thicker pieces of wood used to support young trees and bushes.

Comment: [Royal Horticultural Society](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/types/trees/staking) also calls it a stake. If that's not exciting or technical enough for the OP, they can always add an adjective or some other descriptor.

Answer (score 0):

Pea-stick

> a long stake or branch upon which garden peas are trained

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pea-stick

Answer (score 0):

Beanpole is another, more specific term for a plant stake.  Specifically refers to the stake portion of a trellis or stake and twine setup, iirc.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).